# pandas groupby count and then conditional mean

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    col1 col2
0    a   100
1    a   200
2    a   150
3    b   1000
4    c   400
5    c   200
```

what I want to do is group by col1 and count the number of occurrences and if count is equal or greater than 2, then calculate mean of col2 for those rows and if not returns null. The output should be:

```
    col1 mean
0    a   150
1    b   
2    c   300
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) + [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.groupby('col1').mean().where(df['col1'].value_counts().ge(2)).reset_index()

#you can select columns you want
#(df.groupby('col1')[['col2']]
#   .mean()
#   .where(df['col1'].value_counts().ge(2)).reset_index())
```

**Output**

```
  col1   col2
0    a  150.0
1    b    NaN
2    c  300.0
```

---

if you really want blanks:

```
df.groupby('col1').mean().where(df['col1'].value_counts().ge(2), '').reset_index()

  col1 col2
0    a  150
1    b     
2    c  300
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Custom `agg` function

```
df.groupby('col1').agg(lambda d: np.nan if len(d) == 1 else d.mean())

       col2
col1       
a     150.0
b       NaN
c     300.0
```

Comment: Sorry for editing your answer by mistaking it with my answer.

Comment: I figured that's what happened (-: no worries.  I happened to witness it in real time and just hit the rollback button.  No harm, no foul.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.mean() if x.count() >= 2 else np.nan)


col1
a    150.0
b      NaN
c    300.0
```

**Edit:**

```
%timeit df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.mean() if x.count() >= 2 else np.nan)
2.36 ms ± 255 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# piRSquared
%timeit df.groupby('col1').agg(lambda d: np.nan if len(d) == 1 else d.mean())
5.9 ms ± 30 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# ansev
%timeit df.groupby('col1').mean().where(df['col1'].value_counts().ge(2)).reset_index()
7.01 ms ± 23.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with `GroupBy` and `mask`:

```
g = df.groupby('col1')
g.mean().mask(g.size().eq(1))

      col2
col1       
a     150.0
b       NaN
c     300.0
```