# pandas groupby where and else

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, where-clause

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    col1 col2
0    a   100
1    a   200
2    a   150
3    b   1000
4    c   400
5    c   200
```

what I want to do is group by col1 and count the number of occurrences and if count is equal or greater than 2, then calculate mean of col2 for those rows and if not apply another function. The output should be:

```
    col1 mean
0    a   150
1    b   whatever aggregator function returns 
2    c   300
```

I followed @ansev solution in here [pandas groupby count and then conditional mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60325296/pandas-groupby-count-and-then-conditional-mean) however I don't want to replace them with NaN and actually want to replace it a value that returns from another function like this:

```
def aggregator(col1, col2):
    return col1+col2
```

Please keep in mind that the actual aggregator function is more complicated and dependent to other tables and this is for just simplifying the question.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. If count is lesser than 2, then what is there to aggregate?

Comment: Good catch! 2 was an arbitrary number!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you need, but you can resolve to `apply`:

```
def aggregator(x):
    if len(x)==1:
        return pd.Series( (x['col1'] + x['col2'].astype(str)).values)
    else: return pd.Series(x['col2'].mean())

df.groupby('col1').apply(aggregator)
```

Output:

```
          0
col1       
a       150
b     b1000
c       300
```